# Jest is not covering super call in my custom error class

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, test-coverage

Well, I just created a custom error class, which extends the Error class, and I'm not directly testing that class, but it is being covered when I test other files that call my custom error.
However, in my constructor I had to call `super(message)` from Error, but it is not being covered by jest.

This is my error class code:

```js
export class ApiError extends Error {
    constructor(public statusCode: number, message: string) {
        super(message);
        this.name = 'ApiError';
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.message = message;

        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, ApiError.prototype);
    }

    static badRequest(message: string): ApiError {
        return new ApiError(400, message);
    }

    static unauthorized(message: string): ApiError {
        return new ApiError(401, message);
    }

    static forbidden(message: string): ApiError {
        return new ApiError(403, message);
    }
}
```

And this is the coverage report:
[image: coverage report]

Just consider `MongooseError.ts` really similar to `ApiError.ts`, both are extending Error and calling `super(message)`.

What should I do, since I'm not calling any method from super class?

PS.: I don't know what other code files I need to share, since the class is being tested on both controllers and also in some services.

Comment: Is this problem solved now?

Answer (score 0):

check your 'tsconfig.json'

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Change the value of the target property to ‘es6’.

"super" is a feature for es6, not es5.